# Laravel Internal Server Error 500 on iPage

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, web-hosting

I created a simple project using Laravel 4.2.
It is working fine on my localhost, but I'm getting a `500 Internal Server Error` on my web server. I use iPage and it does support php up to 5.5.

I truly have no idea how to debug this, so if you need more information please do advise and I will edit my question to include it.

So far, this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: Error log

```
20150130T124355: skwat.lightradius.com/index.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /hermes/bosoraweb124/b182/ipg.shosanesnaecom/skwat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 426
```

How can I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to apache logs?

Comment: I'd highly recommend tailing the error logs and seeing what kind of error is generating that 500.

Comment: @marian0 I've asked support for them, I'll post them as soon as I get them.

Comment: This code looks fine but you need to tell what does `error.log` show for 500 error

Comment: I've got the error log now: 20150130T124355: skwat.lightradius.com/index.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /hermes/bosoraweb124/b182/ipg.shosanesnaecom/skwat/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you've posted, your web server must be running PHP < 5.4

The line referenced in your error is using the "new" alternate array syntax:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L426

```
$results = [];
```

This was introduced in PHP 5.4:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-96

Comment: According to iPage - PHP Version: 5.5.32. I'll ask support though.

Comment: @Tiago in your question, you mention that iPage "supports" up to 5.5. When you talk to support, just make sure that's what your app is actually running on.

Comment: You were correct: "Unfortunately, we don't support php 5.4 on our shared server." @mopo922